# How to link InkToolbar to an InkCanvas which is inside CustomControl?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am creating a CustomControl which contain `InkCanvas`. Now the problem is How do I link `InkToolbar`(which is outside the CustomControl) to an `InkCanvas`(which is inside the CustomControl)?

**Solution Tried:**

I tried to get the `InkCanvas` outside the CustomControl using below code but It is **not working**.

**Here is my code**(With the solution I tried which is **not working**):

```
//In CustomControl Code Behind
InkCanvas PATH_INK_CANVAS;

protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    PATH_INK_CANVAS = GetTemplateChild<InkCanvas>("PATH_INK_CANVAS");
}

T GetTemplateChild<T>(string elementName) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var element = GetTemplateChild(elementName) as T;
    if (element == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException(elementName);
    return element;
}

public InkCanvas InkCanvas
{
    get { return PATH_INK_CANVAS; }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InkCanvasProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("InkCanvas", typeof(InkCanvas), typeof(RichInkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));

//In CustomControl XAML
<Style>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Name="MainGrid" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <InkCanvas Name="PATH_INK_CANVAS" Canvas.ZIndex="-1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

//In Page
<local:CustomControl x:Name="MyCustomControl"/>
<InkToolbar Grid.Row="0" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind MyCustomControl.InkCanvas}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's the right syntax to define a *read-only* dependency property. Try something like the following instead -

```
public InkCanvas InkCanvas
{
    get => (InkCanvas)GetValue(InkCanvasProperty);
    private set => SetValue(InkCanvasProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty InkCanvasProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InkCanvas", typeof(InkCanvas), typeof(InkCanvasWrapper), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Also, make sure you set the `Mode` of the `x:Bind` to `OneWay` as the default value of the `InkCanvas` dependency property is `null` (you are setting the default value to `0` which is wrong).

```
<InkToolbar Grid.Row="0" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind MyCustomControl.InkCanvas, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: You should remove that local `PATH_INK_CANVAS` btw.

Comment: Then how do I get the InkCanvas to do other kinds of work? Wait I will give you my code.

Comment: Here is [my code](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/RichInkTextBox-CustomControl). I am trying to create a Control which supports both Inking and Text Editing. Here is the link to UWPCommunityToolkit [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1081UWPCommunityToolkit).

Comment: Can we solve this issue first? Have you got the binding working yet?

Comment: No. That's why I gave you the code to find the error.